# How to pass child variables to parent in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using two components, `SelectTag` and the main component, `SettingsComponent`. The select component is a simple directive with a selector, but the issue I'm having is updating a parent variable from the child component.

For example: I have an `ngModel` binding to a variable (`name`) in the selector component, but how can I access this from the parent component (settings)?

What I've tried so far is using the Angular `EventEmitter`:

```
@Output() onNameChange: EventEmitter<string>;
```

...and accessing it through

```
<select-tag (onNameChange)="name = $event">
```

Is there a better practice to doing this?

Comment: Check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/app-input-output-practice)

Comment: You can do using `@Output`, using a service, or, if you pass an object -not a string or number- you has make nothing, see a silly example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zp6ryf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options to share data between Child and Parent Components.
The best way is probably using an `EventEmitter` like you already tried, just make sure to trigger the event when you want to update.
For example:

```
export class ChildComponent {

  @Output() nameUpdate: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  updateParent(name){
    this.nameUpdate.emit(name)
  }

}
```

`child.component.html`:

```
<input (input)="updateParent($event.target.value)">
```

Now the parent who's using this child selector can listen to the `nameUpdate` event:

```
<app-child (nameUpdate)="nameUpdate($event)">
```

You will get the new value within the `$event`.

You can also consider using services and DI to share data across components, or any other state management tools. But, if your components are in a sibling relationship, Use the `Input` and `Output` decorators as the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a centralized centralized.service.ts component to distribute the data to your components, this way you get it centralized and easy to control the data flow when your app grow:

```
export class CentralizedService {
   private sharedData = {};

   getSharedData(){
      return this.sharedData
   }

   updateSharedData(data){
     //Statements 
   }
}
```

And inject the service to your module and get access to it in both your component

```
constructor(private centralizedService: CentralizedService){}

ngOnInit(){
 this.componentData = this.centralizedService.getSharedData();
}

//Create a method to update shared data 
updateSharedData(data) {
 this.centralizedService.updateSharedData(data);
}
```